# Java OSX : CGContextXXX: invalid context 0x0 in System.err when I call setVisible(true)

Tags: java, macos, swing

I see in `System.err`

```
%DATE% %USERNAME%.local java[%PID%] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
%DATE% %USERNAME%.local java[%PID%] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
%DATE% %USERNAME%.local java[%PID%] <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
%DATE% %USERNAME%.local java[%PID%] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
```

always when I call `setVisible(true)` on `JFrame` of `JDialog`

I use java `1.7_09`

Which root of this messages?

---

Update

OSX 10.8.3

Comment: for all (Swing&) OSX user could be important to see code generated this issue, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable and generated a.m. exception

Comment: See also this [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2399029).

Comment: Which version of OS X is this? Have you tried other JVMs, either other versions or other compilations?